# How to check if key not pressed in GLUT?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I making a game in OpenGL and now, I have a bug in my camera:

- If I press `shift+l` or `shift+k` (move camera), camera will move until I press another key.

To test my camera, add `createKillerBlock(x, y)` in display function after `playerCameraFunc()` function in `if` statement (For example, `createKillerBlock(20, 20)`).

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <GL/glut.h>

#define WINDOW_X 1920
#define WINDOW_Y 1080

#define DEFAULT_PLAYER_SPAWN_X 3.0
#define DEFAULT_PLAYER_SPAWN_Y 3.0

#define DEFAULT_CAMERA_X 0.0
#define DEFAULT_CAMERA_Y 0.0

#define UNKILLABLE_LOCATION 1.01

bool isGameStart = false;

int shiftLPresses = 0;
int shiftKPresses = 0;
int shiftXPresses = 0;
int shiftCPresses = 0;

char pressedKey1, pressedKey2;

float blockSize = 10;

float playerX = DEFAULT_PLAYER_SPAWN_X;
float playerY = DEFAULT_PLAYER_SPAWN_Y;

float playerR = 255;
float playerG = 255;
float playerB = 255;

float playerMoveSpeed = 0.7;

float cameraX = DEFAULT_CAMERA_X;
float cameraY = DEFAULT_CAMERA_Y;

float cameraMoveSpeed = 7.1;

float killerBlockX = UNKILLABLE_LOCATION;
float killerBlockY = UNKILLABLE_LOCATION;

float killerBlockR = 255;
float killerBlockG = 0;
float killerBlockB = 0;

void gameMenu()
{
    if (isGameStart == false)
    {
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, -0.2);
        glVertex2f(0.2, -0.2);
        glVertex2f(0.2, -0.2);
        glVertex2f(0.2, 0.2);
        glVertex2f(0.2, 0.2);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.2);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.2);
        glVertex2f(-0.2, -0.2);
        glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(-0.1, -0.1);
        glVertex2f(0.1, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(-0.1, 0.1);
        glEnd();
    }
}

void startGame()
{
    isGameStart = true;
}

void spawnPlayer()
{
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(playerR / 255, playerG / 255, playerB / 255);
    glVertex2f(-1.0 + (playerX * (blockSize / WINDOW_X)), -1.0 + (playerY * (blockSize / WINDOW_Y)));
    glVertex2f(-1.0 + (playerX * (blockSize / WINDOW_X) + (blockSize / WINDOW_X)), -1.0 + (playerY * (blockSize / WINDOW_Y)));
    glVertex2f(-1.0 + (playerX * (blockSize / WINDOW_X) + (blockSize / WINDOW_X)), -1.0 + (playerY * (blockSize / WINDOW_Y) + (blockSize / WINDOW_Y)));
    glVertex2f(-1.0 + (playerX * (blockSize / WINDOW_X)), -1.0 + (playerY * (blockSize / WINDOW_Y) + (blockSize / WINDOW_Y)));
    glEnd();
}

void playerCameraFunc()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(cameraX * (blockSize / WINDOW_X), cameraY * (blockSize / WINDOW_Y), 0);
}

void killPlayer()
{
    isGameStart = false;
    pressedKey1 = '\0';
    pressedKey2 = '\0';
    playerX = DEFAULT_PLAYER_SPAWN_X;
    playerY = DEFAULT_PLAYER_SPAWN_Y;
    cameraX = DEFAULT_CAMERA_X;
    cameraY = DEFAULT_CAMERA_Y;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void playerKillFunc()
{
    if (playerX >= killerBlockX - 1.0 & playerY >= killerBlockY - 1.0 & playerX < killerBlockX + 1.0 & playerY <= killerBlockY + 1.0)
    {
        if (killerBlockX != UNKILLABLE_LOCATION & killerBlockY != UNKILLABLE_LOCATION)
        {
            killPlayer();
        }
    }
}

void createKillerBlock(int x, int y)
{
    killerBlockX = x;
    killerBlockY = y;
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(killerBlockR / 255, killerBlockG / 255, killerBlockB / 255);
    glVertex2f(-1.0 + (x * (blockSize / WINDOW_X)), -1.0 + (y * (blockSize / WINDOW_Y)));
    glVertex2f(-1.0 + (x * (blockSize / WINDOW_X) + (blockSize / WINDOW_X)), -1.0 + (y * (blockSize / WINDOW_Y)));
    glVertex2f(-1.0 + (x * (blockSize / WINDOW_X) + (blockSize / WINDOW_X)), -1.0 + (y * (blockSize / WINDOW_Y) + (blockSize / WINDOW_Y)));
    glVertex2f(-1.0 + (x * (blockSize / WINDOW_X)), -1.0 + (y * (blockSize / WINDOW_Y) + (blockSize / WINDOW_Y)));
    glEnd();
    playerKillFunc();
}

void timer1()
{
    glutTimerFunc(1000 / 60, timer1, 0);
    switch (pressedKey1)
    {
        case 'w':
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                playerY += playerMoveSpeed / (60 * (shiftXPresses + 1) / (shiftCPresses + 1));
            }
            break;
        case 'a':
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                playerX -= playerMoveSpeed / (60 * (shiftXPresses + 1) / (shiftCPresses + 1));;
            }
            break;
        case 's':
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                playerY -= playerMoveSpeed / (60 * (shiftXPresses + 1) / (shiftCPresses + 1));
            }
            break;
        case 'd':
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                playerX += playerMoveSpeed / (60 * (shiftXPresses + 1) / (shiftCPresses + 1));
            }
            break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void timer2()
{
    glutTimerFunc(1000 / 60, timer2, 0);
    switch (pressedKey2)
    {
        case 76:
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                cameraX -= cameraMoveSpeed / (60 * (shiftLPresses + shiftKPresses + 1));
                playerX += cameraMoveSpeed / (60 * (shiftLPresses + shiftKPresses + 1));
            }
            break;
        case 75:
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                cameraX += cameraMoveSpeed / (60 * (shiftKPresses + shiftLPresses + 1));
                playerX -= cameraMoveSpeed / (60 * (shiftKPresses + shiftLPresses + 1));
            }
            break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gameMenu();
    if (isGameStart == true)
    {
        spawnPlayer();
        playerCameraFunc();
    }
    glFlush();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case 'w':
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                pressedKey1 = 'w';
                pressedKey2 = '\0';
                timer1();
            }
            break;
        case 'a':
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                pressedKey1 = 'a';
                pressedKey2 = '\0';
                timer1();
            }
            break;
        case 's':
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                pressedKey1 = 's';
                pressedKey2 = '\0';
                timer1();
            }
            break;
        case 'd':
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                pressedKey1 = 'd';
                pressedKey2 = '\0';
                timer1();
            }
            break;
        case 76:
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                shiftLPresses += 1;
                pressedKey2 = 76;
                timer2();
            }
            break;
        case 75:
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                shiftKPresses += 1;
                pressedKey2 = 75;
                timer2();
            }
            break;
        case 88:
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                shiftXPresses += 1;
                pressedKey2 = '\0';
                timer1();
            }
            break;
        case 67:
            if (isGameStart == true)
            {
                shiftCPresses += 1;
                pressedKey2 = '\0';
                timer1();
            }
            break;
        case 13:
            if (isGameStart == false)
            {
                startGame();
                timer1();
            }
            break;
        default:
            pressedKey2 = '\0';
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenAttack1");
    glutFullScreen();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

**Edit**

I want to move camera if `shift+l` or `shift+k` keys pressed, but stop moving camera if `shift+l` or `shift+k` not pressed.

Comment: Why do you call `spawnPlayer()` before `playerCameraFunc()`?

Comment: I tried to call `spawnPlayer()` after `playerCameraFunc()`. But nothing changed.

Comment: You're increasing variables with names like `shiftKPresses` but I don't see where they're decreased or set to zero. I'm guessing this is why things are getting out of control.

Comment: @TimRandall I think you did not read my code completely. Did you read e.g. this (`cameraX -= cameraMoveSpeed / (60 * (shiftLPresses + shiftKPresses + 1));`) line?

Comment: @TimRandall My problem is not speed. My problem is that camera will not stop moving unless I press another key.

Comment: @ArianKG I see that you're adding the two values together. Two values which begin at zero, and are occasionally increased, but never decreased or set to zero. As I said, I believe that this is why things are getting out of control. To be clear, I think you need figure out when to zero these variables. Or possibly change the line to `cameraX -= cameraMoveSpeed / (60 * (shiftLPresses - shiftKPresses + 1));` so that the two values are used to move the camera in opposite directions.

Comment: `a / ((b + 1) * c)` is smaller than `a / (b * c)`.

Comment: Perhaps if you named your functions and variables based on their function or purpose, rather than when they're called or changed, the code would be easier to follow and reason about. It might also help if you explained why there are two timer functions. What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to a GLUT 4+ implementation like [FreeGLUT](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT) & register a [`glutKeyboardUpFunc()`](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/include/GL/freeglut_std.h#L501)/[`glutSpecialUpFunc()`](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/include/GL/freeglut_std.h#L502) callback to get notified when a key is released:

> [3.4.4 Changes to Callbacks](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#Background)
>
> Several new callbacks have been added and several callbacks which were specific to Silicon Graphics hardware have not been implemented. Most or all of the new callbacks are listed in the GLUT Version 4 "glut.h" header file but did not make it into the documentation. **The new callbacks consist of regular and special key release callbacks**, a joystick callback, a menu state callback (with one argument, distinct from the menu status callback which has three arguments), a window status callback (also with one argument), and a window position callback. Unsupported callbacks are the two Tablet callbacks. If the user has a need for an unsupported callback he should contact the freeglut development team.

[Usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20487831/44729).