# Moving multiple 2D shapes in OpenGL with key press

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, keypress, glut

I'm currently wanting to make it so that these shapes can be each individually moved when I press a certain key, but am not sure how to properly implement this; I have looked at this question [How do I make a simple 2D shape move using the keyboard with GLUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483286/how-do-i-make-a-simple-2d-shape-move-using-the-keyboard-with-glut) but am still unsure how to assign a key to move each different shape left, right, up and down.

```
//
//INCLUDE STATEMENTS FOR MS WINDOWS:
#include <windows.h>   // for MS Windows
#include <GL/glut.h>   // GLUT, include glu.h and gl.h
/* Initialize OpenGL Graphics */
void initGL() {
    // Set "clearing" or background color
     glClearColor ( 0.0f ,  0.0f ,  0.0f ,  1.0f ); // Black and opaque
}
/* Handler for window-repaint event. Call back when the window first appears and
whenever the window needs to be re-painted. */
void display() {
     glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );   // Clear the color buffer with current clearing color
    
    // Define shapes enclosed within a pair of glBegin and glEnd
     glBegin ( GL_QUADS );              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
     glColor3f (1.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f );  // Red
     glVertex2f (- 0.6f ,  0.2f );     // Define vertices in counter-clockwise (CCW) order
     glVertex2f (- 0.2f ,  0.2f );     //   so that the normal (front-face) is facing you
    glVertex2f (- 0.2f ,  0.4f );
    glVertex2f (- 0.6f ,  0.4f );
     glEnd();
    
     glBegin ( GL_TRIANGLES );          // Each set of 3 vertices form a triangle
     glColor3f (0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f );  // Blue
    glVertex2f ( - 0.4f , 0.5f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.0f , 0.5f );
    glVertex2f ( - 0.2f , 0.8f );
     glEnd();
    
     glBegin( GL_POLYGON );            // These vertices form a closed polygon
     glColor3f (1.0f , 1.0f , 0.0f );  // Yellow
    glVertex2f ( 0.2f ,  0.0f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.4f ,  0.0f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.5f ,  0.2f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.4f ,  0.4f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.2f ,  0.4f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.1f ,  0.2f );
     glEnd();
     
         glBegin( GL_POLYGON );            // These vertices form a closed polygon
     glColor3f (0.0f , 1.0f , 0.0f );  // Green
    glVertex2f ( 0.6f ,  0.3f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.8f ,  0.3f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.9f ,  0.5f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.7f ,  0.7f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.5f ,  0.5f );
     glEnd();
}
int main( int argc,  char** argv) {
glutInit(&argc, argv);            // Initialize GLUT
glutCreateWindow ( "Vertex, Primitive & Color" );  // Create window with the given title
glutInitWindowSize ( 320 ,  320 );   // Set the window's initial width & height
glutInitWindowPosition ( 50 ,  50 ); // Position the window's initial top-left corner
glutDisplayFunc ( display );       // Register callback handler for window re-paint event
initGL ();
glutMainLoop ();
return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the individual x/y positions to a variable, so that whenever you press a key the variable changes, and the shape moves. For example:

```
glBegin ( GL_QUADS );              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
     glColor3f (1.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f );  // Red
     glVertex2f (xPos - 0.6f ,  yPos + 0.2f );     // Define vertices in counter-clockwise (CCW) order
     glVertex2f (xPos - 0.2f ,  yPos + 0.2f );     //   so that the normal (front-face) is facing you
    glVertex2f (xPos - 0.2f ,  yPos + 0.4f );
    glVertex2f (xPos - 0.6f ,  yPos + 0.4f );
 glEnd();
 
 //draw loop or whatever
 
 while(true){
  if(GetAsyncKeyState('W')){
    yPos += .025;
  }
  if(GetAsyncKeyState('A')){
    xPos -= .025;
  }
  if(GetAsyncKeyState('S')){
    yPos -= .025;
  }
  if(GetAsyncKeyState('D')){
    xPos += .025;
  }
 }
```