# How to pause rotation of 2D shapes with mouse input?

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glut, mouseclick-event

I managed to make it so that these 2D shapes move when I press a special key, and also rotate on their own. My next goal is to make it so that the rotation will stop when I mouse click. Any advice on how to do this please?

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <map>

GLfloat angle = 0.0f;
int refreshMills = 30;

std::map< int, bool > keys;
void special( int key, int x, int y )
{
    keys[ key ] = true;
}
void specialUp( int key, int x, int y )
{
    keys[ key ] = false;
}

/* Callback handler for mouse event */
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
//No idea what to put in here
      }

void display()
{
    static float xpos = 0;
    static float ypos = 0;
    static float xpos1 = 0;
    static float ypos1 = 0;
    static float xpos2 = 0;
    static float ypos2 = 0;

    const float speed = 0.02;
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_LEFT ] )
    {
        xpos -= speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_RIGHT ] )
    {
        xpos += speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_UP ] )
    {
        ypos += speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_DOWN ] )
    {
        ypos -= speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_F1 ] )
    {
        xpos1 -= speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_F2 ] )
    {
        xpos1 += speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_F3 ] )
    {
        ypos1 += speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_F4 ] )
    {
        ypos1 -= speed;
    }if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_F5 ] )
    {
        xpos2 -= speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_F6 ] )
    {
        xpos2 += speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_F7 ] )
    {
        ypos2 += speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_F8 ] ) 
    {
        ypos2 -= speed;
    }
    

    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
 glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef( xpos, ypos, 0 );
    glTranslatef(-0.9, 0.90, 0);
     glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // rotate by angle in degrees
    glBegin ( GL_QUADS );              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
     glColor3f (1.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f );  // Red
    glVertex2f (- 0.6f ,  0.2f );     // Define vertices in counter-clockwise (CCW) order
    glVertex2f (- 0.2f ,  0.2f );     //   so that the normal (front-face) is facing you
    glVertex2f (- 0.2f ,  0.4f );
    glVertex2f (- 0.6f ,  0.4f );
     glEnd();
     glPopMatrix(); 
    
    glLoadIdentity();
     glPushMatrix(); 
     glTranslatef( xpos1, ypos1, 0 );
     glTranslatef(-0.9, 0.90, 0);
 glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // rotate by angle in degrees
     glBegin ( GL_TRIANGLES );          // Each set of 3 vertices form a triangle
     glColor3f (0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f );  // Blue
    glVertex2f ( - 0.4f , 0.5f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.0f , 0.5f );
    glVertex2f ( - 0.2f , 0.8f );
     glEnd();
     glPopMatrix(); 
     
    glLoadIdentity();
     glPushMatrix(); 
     glTranslatef( xpos2, ypos2, 0 );
     glTranslatef(-0.9, 0.90, 0);
 glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // rotate by angle in degrees
     glBegin( GL_POLYGON );            // These vertices form a closed polygon
     glColor3f (0.0f , 1.0f , 0.0f );  // Green
    glVertex2f ( 0.6f ,  0.3f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.8f ,  0.3f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.9f ,  0.5f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.7f ,  0.7f );
    glVertex2f ( 0.5f ,  0.5f );
     glEnd();
     glPopMatrix(); 

     glutSwapBuffers();
        angle += 2.0f;
}

void Timer( int value )
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(refreshMills, Timer, 0); // next Timer call milliseconds later
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600 , 600 );
    glutInitWindowPosition ( 50 ,  50 ); // Position the window's initial top-left corner
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    //glutMouseFunc ( mouse );   // Register callback handler for mouse event
    glutSpecialFunc( special );
    glutSpecialUpFunc( specialUp );
    glutTimerFunc( 0, Timer, 0 );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

[How do I make a simple 2D shape move using the keyboard with GLUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483286/how-do-i-make-a-simple-2d-shape-move-using-the-keyboard-with-glut) : heavy reference used

Comment: Drive your update routine with a timer, and control the rotation state with a variable (_e.g._ rotation speed, which you set to zero when the mouse is clicked).

Answer (score 0):

Like the one comment said, you can just use a variable to control rotation speed. If you want to separate this further into two useful functions, here's what I would do:

- Store the rotation speed as an `int`, `float`, whatever data type you want for the precision, and make that modifiable with two keys for increasing or decreasing (eg you press, say, 'q' to speed up the rotation and 'e' to slow it down, but these keys can be whatever you like. This way you can easily control *how fast* they are rotating
- Store a `bool` called something like `shouldRotate`, and in the main window rendering loop, check every frame and only do the rotation if `shouldRotate` is set to `true`, and upon a mouse click (or being held down) change the value of `shouldRotate` to `false`, or invert it, however you like depending on how you want this option to toggle. This way you can easily control *whether they are rotating at all*.

Also, as a personal suggestion, I would do the rotations based on some form of `deltaTime` in conjunction with the constant speed variable, to account for different machines and framerates the program could run on. If you're unfamiliar with the concept, it just is a measure of time between frames so that physics code can run consistently, rather than varying with the framerate.

The implementation is fairly simple too; just create `deltaTime` and `timeLastFrame` variables, and every new frame using some form of system time, or the GLUT timer function (forgive me but I'm not very familiar with GLUT, I use GLAD/glfw3 with OpenGL) check how much time has passed since the time stored in `timeLastFrame`, set `deltaTime` to this difference, and set `timeLastFrame` to the current system time for use in the next loop. Then when you rotate your objects you can multiply the speed by `deltaTime` so they always move a constant amount over a second, rather than a constant amount by frame :)